# Please how do I get these lines of codes to run error free

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, mysql-workbench

I keep getting this error `" The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator"` while running this lines of code on SQL.
 --I desire to obtain the names, texts and Last_authors considering their most recent entries.

```
Select PR1.Name, PR1.TText, PR1.Author as Last_Author 
From PageRevision as PR1, PageRevision as PR2 
Group by Pr1.Name, PR1.TText 
Having PR1.DDate = max(PR2.DDate);
```

Comment: you will to `cast` the `text field` into `varchar` to compare

Comment: You really shouldn't be using text/ntext data types. If you can change them, do that. Also, from the looks of your query, you're trying to get the last author (by the ddate) for each name/ttext combination - you should use something like the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function for this (partition by name, ttext order by ddate desc) instead of grouping.

Comment: mysql != sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Well seems the easiest way is just do this.

```
Select PR1.Name, PR1.TText, PR1.Author as Last_Author 
From PageRevision as PR1
inner join (
Select name, ttext,author
        ,max(ddate) ddate
        From Pagerevision
        group by name, ttext,author
        ) pr2
on pr1.name = pr2.name
and pr1.ttext = pr2.ttext
and pr1.author = pr2.author
and pr1.ddate = pr2.ddate
```

Comment: Thanks. But this will return only one tuple which has the max ddate.I want to see updated tuples but in a case where there is none i want the old tuples displayed.

Comment: Sorry about that going to fast sometimes :)